# How to make Fedora workstation faster

Tags: fedora, performance

I use Fedora workstation 33  as my main system (coding, browsing, office...), on an 8gb , i3, slow hdd laptop. What are some tips to make it faster?

Comment: Nobody can answer your question with any authority.  Why?   You have provided zero information about your hardware, workloads, or even the version of Fedora you are using.

Comment: Probably switching to an SSD, even a really cheap one.

Answer (score -4):

## 1. Uninstall useless packages

This removes services & frees up space

```
#watch the deps!
dnf rm abrt avahi audit adobe-mappings-cmap ModemManager 
dnf rm containernetworking-plugins cups cups-client empathy evolution evince fedora-workstation-backgrounds f31-backgrounds-base flatpak foomatic-db-ppds fpaste
dnf rm geolite2-city gnome-classic-session gnome-contacts gnome-getting-started-docs  gnome-user-docs gnome-tour gssproxy gutenprint gvfs-gphoto2 gucharmap iok 'hplip*' 'kde*' libpurple libreoffice-emailmerge libreoffice-math
dnf rm libreport
dnf rm m17n-contrib mcelog  'qemu*' qt-x11 orca 
dnf rm open-vm-tools pcsc-lite pcsc-lite-libs php-common redis rhythmbox rng-tools samba-client sane-backends sane-backends-libs shotwell 'selinux-policy*' sssd 'libsss_*' totem tracker-miners
dnf rm virtualbox-guest-additions vim-filesystem vim-minimal yum
# i18n
dnf rm libpinyin libkkc libkkc-data libhangul opencc   thai-scalable-fonts-common   nhn-nanum-gothic-fonts wqy-zenhei-fonts smc-fonts-common    smc-meera-fonts skkdic cjkuni-uming-fonts
dnf rm PackageKit
```

## 2. Disable useless services

```
DISABLE_SERVICES="atd dnf-makecache firewalld mdmonitor NetworkManager-wait-online redis unbound-anchor.timer"; for i in $DISABLE_SERVICES; do systemctl stop $i;  systemctl disable $i; done
```

## 3. Analyze what's left

```
# see active services
systemctl -t service --state=active

# see what's taking boot time
systemd-analyze blame

# see largest packages
rpm -qa --queryformat '%{name}-%{version}-%{release} %{size}\n' | sort -nr -k2 | head -n 100 | less

# list top 10 largest open files
lsof / | awk '{ if($7 > 1048576) print $7/1048576 "MB "$9 }' | sort -n -u | tail
```

## 4. Disable selinux

```
nano /etc/selinux/config
SELINUX=disabled
```

Comment: Disabling SELinux doesn't make Fedora faster, it makes it less secure. Also removing "random" packages will safe you some harddisk space, but won't necessary make your system faster -- if you want a minimal system, I'd recommend using netinstall image, installing minimal system and installing only packages you want /need.